# German old handwriting recognition - help

Tags: german-to-english, handwriting, kurrent

[image]
Can somebody help me with this german word. I have this handwriting in one picture. What is name of place [image]

This is found on one picture from my grandfather. He worked in Austria. And this is one place in Austria.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site.

Answer (score 12):

The handwriting is [Kurrent](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Kurrentschrift) and I can recognise the letters as follows:

1. The first letter is clearly an *E.*
2. The second letter is clearly a *b*.
3. The third letter is most likely an *e.* It could also be an *n,* but those are usually wider.
4. My best guess on number four is an exotic *r,* but it could also be an *n* or even *e* gone wrong.
5. Number five is most likely an *s.* This is noteworthy, as this letter was only used inside of words under special conditions, namely:

   - at the end of non-inflectory morphemes,
   - at the end of a syllable if the following letter was not *p, t,* or *z* and the *s* was not part of a polygraph (like *ss* or *sch*).

   What is weird is the long “pause” made before this letter as you would rather make one afterwards sementically, given that it occurs only at the end of something.
6. The zig-zag lines at the end could be any combination of the following letters with a total of four stems: *i, n, m, u,* and *e,* with the latter counting for two stems. One of the letters could be a *c* (counting one stem) but that’s highly unlikely as this letter rarely occured without being followed by *h* or *k* in non-loanwords (which this one seems to be).

   Importantly, the letters *i* and *u* are marked by a dot or short stroke placed above the character, which could be the small squiggle in the top right of your picture.

   Finally, it could be that the stroke that descends from the swash of the *s* does not belong to it but is actually the *i* dot.

   My best guess is *nu* but it could also be *im* and many other things.

This would leave us at something like *Ebers-nu* or *Ebers-im,* both of which do not look very German. Without more context, it is impossible to tell you anything more about it.

Comment: Could the zigzag line be a (strange) w and could the squiggle be an indicator that the name is abbreviated? "Ebersw" (note the final *s*!) might be an abbreviation for "Eberswalde".

Comment: Alternatively: Could the letter following the final *s* be an *a*? "Ebersau" is an actual place name.

Comment: @Uwe: I doubt that your first guess is correct as a Kurrent *w* almost always ends in some sort of swash – in contrast to a modern w. — As for your second suggestion: It’s unlikely, but possible.

Comment: it could get some perspective on the weird "pause". Eber-sau.. just because its old does not mean it could not contain bad puns

Comment: @Bort: But then, *Eber-sau* would be written *Eberſau,* not *Ebersau.* So, you do not need a subtly hidden pause for this pun.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft well you do under the premise that you do not want to misspell it

Comment: Looking at the rest of the text @Uwe's second guess becomes less unlikely: the writer seems not to "close" the letter 'a' as it normally should, as you can see in the words _an_ and _Familie_. What follows the ſ looks quite similar to these two other occurences of 'a'.

Comment: @Matthias Leaving the "a" open at the top is not at all unusual in Kurrent. The strange thing is that there is no trace of an angle in the right half of the letter; it's perfectly rounded, rather than broken. On the other hand, any other candidate letter, such as "u", "i", "n", or "m" should also be angled in some way.

Answer (score 8):

**Ebersau.**

**Ebersau** ist ein Ort im Innviertel von Oberösterreich wie auch eine Ortschaft in der Gemeinde Schildorn im Bezirk Ried im Innkreis.

Der Ortsname **Ebersawe** ist ein -au-Name. Eine Au ist ein **Feuchtgebiet an einem Bach oder Fluss**. Es handelte sich also ursprünglich um die **Au des Ēbur** um 1200. (Dieser Vorname bedeutet Eber.)

z. T. nach:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebersau

Answer (score 5):

This is the written Text:

> Zur Erinnerung
>   an meine Dienstzeit
>
> an Familie Hörbiger
>   zu **Ebersau**

Comment: I think the second _an_ is rather a _von_.